# TFS 2017 change existing parameter of custom build task

Tags: json, powershell, tfs

In the json file of a custom build task I have changed the value which will be sent to the powershell script when you select a parameter:

```
{
  "name": "VerbosityLevel",
  "type": "pickList",
  "label": "Level of Verbosity",
  "required": true,
  "helpMarkDown": "Select Verbosity level",
  "defaultValue": "-v:n",
  "options": {
    "quiet": "quiet",
    "minimal": "minimal",
    "normal": "normal",
    "detailed": "detailed",
    "diagnostic": "diagnostic"
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "name": "VerbosityLevel",
  "type": "pickList",
  "label": "Level of Verbosity",
  "required": true,
  "helpMarkDown": "Select Verbosity level",
  "defaultValue": "-v:n",
  "options": {
    "-v:q": "quiet",
    "-v:m": "minimal",
    "-v:n": "normal",
    "-v:d": "detailed",
    "-v:diag": "diagnostic"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, all build definitions that were already existing before the change and had that build step do not get updated and still contain the old values. 
[Link to Build Definition json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDRmv.png)

Is there any efficient way to update all preexisting build definitions when you change something on an already existing parameter?

Comment: My understanding was that if your task version number is updated it gets pulled down as part of your build start and the build task should not need updating. Have you tried deleting the existing task in the agent folder and then see what gets pulled down when job runs? Is it still the old version then?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [version of the task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/tasks#task-versions) in task.json such as below:

```
"version": {
        "Major": 2,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Patch": 57
    },
```

You could directly update the version of task such as change 2.0.57 to 2.0.58...the changes will automatically replaced in all preexisting build definitions including the task.

However, if you change the major version of the task such as 2.0.57 to 3.0.57. You need to manually select the version in the top of the task such as below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have increased the patch value in my scenario and uploaded the task with the increased version number. The old values persist in old build definitions. It will only change to the new values of the parameter when you edit anything in the build definition and save the changes.

Comment: @CheesusCrust Got the same result as you in my side. In my opinion, this  should also make sense. If the build in preexisting build definitions always pass and suddenly fail due to one of the task version update/parameter changed and  without any signal, which also doesn't make sense. So I'm afraid you have to edit anything in the old build definition to complete the synchronization.

Comment: Sadly, for us this is a dilemma since this would mean we would have to manually go into every of our 100 build definitions and edit them manually when we change one parameter in our custom build task.